# Unable to open deeplink through gmail app

Tags: android, gmail, android-deep-link

I recieve a link on gmail and I want to open my application whenever we click on that link.
If I click on that link, it opens in the website(not in app), but if I copy that link and open it in the browser it gives me an option to choose the application.

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="agora-frontend.herokuapp.com"
                android:scheme="https" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="agora-frontend.herokuapp.com"
                android:scheme="http" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="agora-frontend.herokuapp.com"
                android:scheme="app" />

        </intent-filter>
```

The link I am trying to open is 
https://agora-frontend.herokuapp.com/vote/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I want to open my app whenever we click on that link through gmail.

Comment: Gmail has an internal browser that sometimes catches these deeplinks. Does it work from other apps like sms or chrome?

Comment: Yes, it works from chrome or sms.

Comment: I am getting the same issue and I cannot find any solution. Did you fix it? thanks